# Styled css do not appear in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

I have a checkbox that I have styled accordingly. Like this :

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
  transform: scale(1.3);
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 17px;
  visibility: hidden;
}

input[type=checkbox]:after {
  content: " ";
  background-color: rgba(224, 214, 214, 0.877);
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 22px;
  height: 25px;
  visibility: visible;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding-left: 3px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked:after {
  content: "\2714";
  padding: -5px;
  background: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="Option1" />
<p>Option1</p>
```

I tested this and it worked in Chrome and Opera, but I forgot to check Firefox.
Now I see that the checkboxes don't appear there at all.
I understand it is an issue of using :after for checkbox, but how do I fix this ?
So that the same checkbox appears styled on the browsers?.
I am uncertain of what to do so that I keep the design.
Thank you.

Comment: You need to make use of a span or a label linked to the checbox and hide the checkbox. I'm not sure that styling the pseudoelement is supported for checkbox in firefox.

Answer (score 2):

> **Read these [specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content)**
>
> :before and :after should only work on the element which can act as a
>   container of content.  cannot contain any content so it should
>   not support those pseudo-elements. Chrome supports because it does not
>   follow the spec

However you can use `<span>` tag next to `input` tag to achieve this like below. It will work on `firefox` as well

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

label span {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox]+span:after {
  content: "";
  background-color: rgba(224, 214, 214, 0.877);
  color: #fff;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  line-height: 30px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked+span:after {
  content: "\2714";
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<label>
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="Option1" />
<span>Option1</span>
</label>
```